# Need help removing time pattern from date in R

Tags: r, gsub

I want to just get rid off the time stamp in my date column.

Using gsub in R. Can't seem to figure out what pattern to use.

```
"2019-04-03T20:31:47Z"
```

Hope for some help. This didn't work so far:

```
gsub("T[:digit:]$", "", week0_album$created)
```

Comment: `as.Date("2019-04-03T20:31:47Z")` or `substr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. The format `"2019-04-03T20:31:47Z"` leads me to believe these dates are from some kind of delimited file (CSV, TSV), so the best thing to do would probably be to import them using the correct data type:

```r
# An example string.
s <- "2019-04-03T20:31:47Z"

# Use `colClasses` to use correct data type on import.
read.csv(text = s, header = F, col.names = "dates", colClasses = "Date")

#### OUTPUT ####

        date
1 2019-04-03
```

You can also use regex, but something simpler would suffice. You really just want to remove everything after `T`, so:

```r
sub("T.*", "", s)
```

But dates are more useful as `Date` objects, so I would recommend converting your strings. You could call `as.Date` on the above string after `sub`bing, but `as.Date` also works quite well alone *(Others have given this answer. I'm just including it for the sake of completeness and because I think it's better practice than just `sub`bing and using the date as a character string.)*:

```r
as.Date(s)
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `anydate` from `anytime`

```
library(anytime)
anydate(str1)
#[1] "2019-04-03"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "2019-04-03T20:31:47Z"
```

Comment: That makes it easy! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `gsub`, just the `as.Date` function from the `base` will solve it.

```
as.Date("2019-04-03T20:31:47Z")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you insist to keeping it basic and a character, this regex will help:

```r
chr <- "2019-04-03T20:31:47Z"
gsub("T[[:digit:]:]{8}Z$", "", chr)
#> [1] "2019-04-03"
```

Comment: This actually did the trick. Since I'm working with a lot of data, gsub is way faster than the `anytime` or `as.Date` I feel like. Thank you!

Comment: `substr` (as mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56600868/need-help-removing-time-pattern-from-date-in-r#comment99777694_56600868)) is faster. `x <- rep("2019-04-03T20:31:47Z", 1e7)`; `system.time(gsub("T[[:digit:]:]{8}Z$", "", x))`; `system.time(substr(x, 1, 10))`

Comment: And probably smarter since in this case you don't even need the flexibility offered by regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)

str <- "2019-04-03T20:31:47Z"
date(str)

# [1] "2019-04-03"
```